# Coupon Logic Prestashop 8.0

Tags: prestashop

How can I add an additional field to each coupon in the system?
Prestashop 8.0 +

I tried creating a module, but the fields are not showing up in the panel.
I can't find anything about it in the documentation.
Thanks :)

```
<?php

class AdminCbSviatoController extends ModuleAdminController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->table = 'cart_rule'; 
        $this->className = 'CartRule'; 
        $this->lang = false;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->fields_list = array(
            'id_cart_rule' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('ID'),
                'align' => 'center',
                'width' => 25,
            ),
            'name' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Balance'),
            ),
            'balance' => array( // 
                'title' => $this->l('Balance'),
                'align' => 'center',
                'type' => 'text',
                'filter_key' => 'a!balance',
            ),
        );

        $this->bulk_actions = array(
            'update' => array(
                'text' => $this->l('Update'),
                'icon' => 'icon-refresh',
            ),
        );
    }
}
```